# Please check the code , not all test run is running fully

Tags: python-3.x, string

You are given a string .
Your task is to find out if the string  contains: alphanumeric characters, alphabetical characters, digits, lowercase and uppercase characters.Please ignore the identations

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
def hasalphanumeric(inputString):
return any(char.isalnum() for char in inputString)
def hasalphabet(inputString):
return any(char.isalpha() for char in inputString)
def hasupper(inputString):
return any(char.isupper() for char in inputString)
def haslower(inputString):
return any(char.islower() for char in inputString)

s=input()
    
if (hasNumbers(s)==True):
print("True")
else:
print("False")

if (hasalphanumeric(s)==True):
print("True")
else:
print("False")            
if (hasalphabet(s)==True):
print("True")
else:
print("False")
if (hasupper(s)==True):
print("True")
else:
print("False")
if (haslower(s)==True):
print("True")
else:
print("False")
```

Comment: Hi, what's your problem? I indented your code and all the tests run. Maybe you have an issue with your indentation...

Comment: what @PieCot said is correct..Fix your intendation